# Measure accuracy of Multiple Linear regression model with differently transformed variables

Tags: r, regression, transformation

I have a relatively small data set that I am trying to model for dependent variable Y. The model that I have currently looks like this:

```r
log(Y) = Bo + B1X1 + B2*log(X2) + B3*(1/X3) + B4*log(X4) + e
```

My R^2 value for this model is .924 but I don't know how to back-transform and analyze predictive accuracy with the inverse independent variable thrown into the mix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to explain what you want more clearly. Your R^2 value *is* an estimate of (within-sample) predictive accuracy, adjusted R^2 or AIC (or cross-validation or [PRESS statistic](https://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/calculating-the-press-statistic-in-r/)) will estimate out-of-sample predictive accuracy.  Where does back-transformation come into this?

Comment: I want to calculate MSE in relation to the original units of Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute MSE for this model on the original (non-logged) scale, all you have to do is exponentiate (back-transform) the predictions. The transformations of the predictor (independent) variables are irrelevant, i.e. something like

```r
mean((exp(predict(fitted_model)) - y_obs)^2)
```

for within-sample MSE or

```r
mean((exp(predict(fitted_model, newdata = ...)) - y_new)^2)
```

for out-of-sample.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I thought I needed to do more but I guess I was just overthinking.